# Have centered and left aligned <li> options in a menu

Tags: html, css, center

I am working on a menu where I want three of the buttons aligned to the left, two things aligned to the right and one other option aligned in the center. I am currently accomplishing this by adding padding to the center aligned one, but I feel as though there is a better way to do this. Especially when someone uses a screen of smaller resolution, such as a cell phone.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
   ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<body bgcolor="#71AAE2">
<div align="center">
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="1200" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#6699FF">
<tr>
<td width="800">
<p align="center">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="800">
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html" style="padding:18px 20px">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="gallery.html" style="padding:18px 20px">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html" style="padding:18px 20px">Contact Us </a></li>
  <li style="float:right"><a href="http://www.gltdc.net/" target="_blank" ><img src="images/GLTDC.png" style="padding:7px 7px;" width="80" height="38"></li>
  <li style="float:right;padding:18px 0px;display: block;color: white;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;">PROUD MEMBER OF THE</li></a>
  <center><li style="display:inline-block;margin-left: 24%;"><a href="Internal/index.html" style="padding:18px 20px">Employee Login</a></li></center>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

So what would be the best way to center that "Employee Login"?

Comment: You have some invalid html (around the fourth list item) so you probably want to fix that first. And is this for email or something? You're using some pretty old syntax.

Comment: You'd better move css styles together and make them more organized. Then if you want to arrange the items in navbar, consider 'flexible box layout'. Try adding `display: flex;  justify-content: space-around;` to in your `ul` style, then check [related page in mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) to find more properties you need.

Comment: It's also not recommended to use *tables* for layout,..and `center` is an obsolete element and should no longer be used.